# Make a 3D Object look like it is facing a point in an 2D space

Tags: c#, google-maps, unity-game-engine, 3d, 2d

The first thing you will notice is the complicated and confusing title.
So let me explain that.

I'm trying to make an 2D game in an 3D space using Unity. And i'm using a 3D Character as an Player. This looks like that :

[image: Pic1]

As you can see the Background ( A Google map ) is two dimensional. While the Player is a 3D Object laying on the ground ( It just Looks like it is Standing ).

Thats working fine so far. But i want that the 3D Character Looks like it is facing a tapped Point on the Background map.

For example :

[image: Hes looking towards]

And two more examples :

[image]

[image]

The black circle represents the tapped Position. So i have totally no clue if theres a way to do that, or even if its possible to do that.

I tried the following code, but that only rotates my character on an different axis :

```
    Vector3 targetDir = tapped.position - transform.position;

    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

    Vector3 newDir = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetDir, step, 0.0F);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDir);
```

Is there even a way to achieve that ? Im currently out of ideas...
I would be very glad for any help i can get !

Comment: Just 0 the y of the target direction.

Comment: @DreamsOfElectricSheep Thanks for your fast answer ! But that doesnt work. The player "Lays" on the ground all the time to create the illusion he would walk on it. When i set y to zero he suddenly really stands on the ground O.o

Comment: i think if you switch y and z it should show this effect. if your target direction is (1,0,1) make him face (1,1,0) instead.

Comment: @yes Thanks for your answer ! Unfortunately that doesnt work either. When i tap somewhere the character either rotates on the wrong axis or even does nothing :/.

Comment: yes after i thought about it for a bit, it was stupid to assume it would be that easy. posted a little snippet for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. Make your model a child of an unrotated empty, facing is like in your first image, and put the below script on it. I didnt know how you get the point to look at, it is what i tried in unity. Hope it helps.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LookAtTarget : MonoBehaviour {

    //assign in inspector
    public Collider floor;

    //make sure you Camera is taged as MainCamera, or make it public and assign in inspector
    Camera mainCamera;

    RaycastHit rayHit;

    //not needed when assigned in the inspector    
    void Start() {
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update () {

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {

            if(floor.Raycast(mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out rayHit, Mathf.Infinity)) {
                //its actually the inverse of the lookDirection, but thats is because the rotation around z later.
                Vector3 lookDirection = transform.position - rayHit.point;

                float angle = Vector3.Angle(lookDirection, transform.forward);

                transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Vector3.Dot(Vector3.right, lookDirection) > 0 ? angle : angle * -1, Vector3.forward);

            } 

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer ! I just tested it. But somehow the Character stands on the map instead of being paralell now. Also he rotates around the z axis. He should be parallel to the map and rotates around the x axis to make him look to the point. And i just get the point by listening for touch inputs and raycasting :)